# How to hide numeric keypad?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

[image]I have a textfield, in which I need the user to type only numeric values. I am using the numeric keypad type. In this keyboard there no done button. I saw an article [here](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key)
which allowed me to add a done button to the keypad.

I can't hide that, however. Here is my code

```
- (void)addButtonToKeyboard {
    // create custom button
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.0) {
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown3.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    } else {        
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        } else {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // if clause is just an additional precaution, you could also dismiss it
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 3.2) {
        [self addButtonToKeyboard];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // if clause is just an additional precaution, you could also dismiss it
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
        [self addButtonToKeyboard];
    }
}
    - (void)doneButton:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"doneButton");
       [anualIncome setText:@"hai"];
        NSLog(@"Input: %@", anualIncome.text);
        [anualIncome resignFirstResponder];

    }
```

kindly guide me where i'm doing wrong.when i press the done button i can see the console output like this

```
Hello World[2542:f803] doneButton
Hello World[2542:f803] Input: (null)
```

i just add my anualincome in to the my veiwconroller.is there any other action should add?this is my outlet

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *anualIncome;
```

Comment: This code looks OK, the problem could be that `anualIncome` is nil - is this an outlet? Can you check it is connected? If you change the last log statement to be `anualIncome` instead of `anualIncome.text` what do you see?

Comment: @jrturton now i change my input in my edit text.now also its showing same out put...

Comment: That supports my theory that anualIncome is `nil`. Check your outlets. How is anualIncome set up?

Comment: @jrturton ya i have connected to my view controller. i have to add any IBaction for done button?.

Comment: the done button seems to be working, since you are seeing the log statements. You still haven't answered my question - is anualIncome nil at the time that method is being executed?

Comment: @jrturton yes your right anualIncome is a problem small issue with my didload method thank u for your guide jrturton.

Comment: jrturton might want to add his response as an answer so that you can mark it as correct. Everybody wins. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using done button you can hide keyboard this way:

Implement touches began method in your viewContoller class like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [anualIncome resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use an `inputAccessoryView` property of the `UITextField` instance to set a `UIToolbar` with any buttons on it. (in fact it can be any UIView subclass) The resulting view will be as it is in the safari, when you filling some text in any web form. It's much easier. Also there's no chance of breaking view in case apple will change their implementation...

Happy coding...